# Math: Add total number from text inputs and find percentages

Tags: jquery, math

I have 2 types of text inputs, positive and questionable. There are multiple sets of these inputs that I need to show the total after adding all the numbers entered into both types of inputs. eg: 2 positive + 2 questionable = Total: 4

Then, I need to find the percentage of positive vs questionable from that total.
eg: 50% positive and 50% questionable.

I want to add these totals and percentages up live as the user enters them.

So far I am not getting anywhere. Any ideas for the best way to do this? Should I use .blur or .each?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/UjU4a/

Here is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
<label>How many positive?</label>
<input type="text" name="positive" class="observationPositive">
<br />

<label>How many questionable?</label>
<input type="text" name="questionable" class="observationQuestionable">
<br />

<hr />

<label>How many positive?</label>
<input type="text" name="positive" class="observationPositive">
<br />

<label>How many questionable?</label>
<input type="text" name="questionable" class="observationQuestionable">
<br />

<hr />

<h4><span  id="observationTotal"></span> Total</h4>
<h4><span  id="observationQuestionablePercentage"></span>% Questionable</h4>
<h4><span  id="observationPositivePercentage"></span>% Positive</h4>

$('.observationPositive').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.observationPositive').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
});​​​​​​​​​
$('#observationTotal').text(sum);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use '.on("change", function(){...})' as opposed to ".change(function(){...})" or ".blur(function(){...})". I would also suggest you change the HTML input types to "number", possibly add the "step", "min", and "max" attributes, making the form nicer to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean "average of the values". However, I could do with understanding more about what it is you are trying to achieve - you might want to pair up each positive input with a questionable input...

```
$('.observationPositive, .observationQuestionable').on("change", function () {
    var sumP = 0,
        sumQ = 0,
        countP = 0,
        countQ = 0;
    $('.observationPositive').each(function(){
        countP++;
        sumP += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.observationQuestionable').each(function(){
        countQ++;
        sumQ += Number($(this).val());
    });

    var percentP = 100/(1 + (sumQ/sumP));
    var percentQ = 100 - percentP;

    $("#observationTotal").text(sumP + sumQ);
    $("#observationQuestionablePercentage").text(percentQ.toFixed(2));
    $("#observationPositivePercentage").text(percentP.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: yes, that works. now to round the number would I use this?  Math.round(num).toFixed(2);

Comment: I've included an update to my answer - as the numeric values already exist, you just need to run ".toFixed(2)" when outputting them. If you are worried about rounding issues, you could also use "100 - percentP.toFixed(2)" when calculating percentQ.